# Get notified of comments on a post in facebook using open graph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

I have an application that I am posting updates to facebook.  I am using the open graph API.  The underlying library has implemented some callback features where you can get notified of updates to a user object like when the user changes their name etc.

However, I want to get a callback when a new comment is made on a post I made or someone likes a post I made.

Right now I would have to query all my posts and see if there are any new comments.  Facebook doesn't give you an ID when you post a comment so you have to go on just the content and user when parsing.

So to my question.  Is there a way to register a callback for when a post is updated?  Does it use the same mechanism as the user one?

Not sure it makes a difference, but the application is in Rails and I am using the Koala Graph api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a comments box social plugin, you can subscribe to the comment.create and comment.remove events to enable you to run a callback that will be passed the id.

Full details are [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)